# SMT let expression binding scope

Tags: z3, smt

I'm using a simple `let` expression to shorten my `SMT` formula. I want bindings to use previously defined bindings as follows, but if I remove the commented line and have `n` refer to `s` it doesn't work:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                   ;
; This is our state ;
;                   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(declare-datatypes ((State 0))
    (((rec
        (myArray String)
        (index   Int))))
)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;                        ;
; This is our function f ;
;                        ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
(define-fun f ((in State)) State
    (let (
          (s   (myArray in))
          (n   (str.len (myArray in))))
;;;;;;;;;;(n   (str.len s)))
     in
         (rec (str.substr s 1 n) 1733))
)
```

I looked at the documentation [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.565.1070&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and it's not clear whether it's indeed forbidden to have bindings refer to other (previously defined) bindings:

> The whole let construct is entirely equivalent to replacing each new
>   parameter by its expression in the target expression, eliminating the
>   new symbols completely (...)

I guess it's a "shallow" replacement?

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to deal with this using a double-nested `let`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Section 3.6.1 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf:

> **Let**. The let binder introduces and defines one or more local variables
>   in parallel. Semantically, a term of the form `(let ((x1 t1) · · · (xn tn)) t)` (3.3) is equivalent to the term `t[t1/x1, . . . , tn/xn]`
>   obtained from t by simultaneously replacing each free occurrence of xi
>   in t by ti , for each i = 1, . . . , n, possibly after a suitable
>   renaming of t’s bound variables to avoid capturing any variables in
>   t1, . . . , tn. Because of the parallel semantics, the variables x1, .
>   . . , xn in (3.3) must be pairwise distinct.
>
> **Remark 3** (No sequential
>   version of let). The language does not have a sequential version of
>   let. Its effect is achieved by nesting lets, as in `(let ((x1 t1)) (let ((x2 t2)) t))`.

As indicated in **Remark 3**, if you want to refer to an earlier definition you have to nest the let-expressions.